# How to replace all double quotes to single quotes using mysql replace?

Tags: mysql, sql, escaping, quotes, mysql5

I need to replace all double quotes to single quotes using mysql query.

How can I do that. My sql should be in double quotes.

```
mysql="select replace(text,'\"',''') from mytable"
```

throwing error. How can I escape that single quotes inside query?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this one

```
 $mysql="select replace(text,'\"',\"'\") from mytable";
```

Then the query will become

```
select replace(text,'"',"'") from mytable
```

at the Mysql end.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the single quote `'` too (see [table 8.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html)):

```
mysql="select replace(text,'\"','\\'') from mytable"
```

Thus, the string sent to MySQL will read:

```
select replace(text,'"','\'') from mytable
```

Comment: I also recommend replacing them inside your database: 
UPDATE tableName SET ColumnName = REPLACE( ColumnName ,'"',"'");
or
UPDATE tableName SET ColumnName = REPLACE( ColumnName ,'\"','\\'');